# How to Resolve this code which is given below

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound

root = Tk()
root.geometry("350x300")
root.configure(bg='ghost white')
root.title("DataFlair - TEXT TO SPEECH")
Label(root, text="TEXT_TO_SPEECH", font="arial 20 bold", bg='white smoke').pack()
Label(text="DataFlair", font='arial 15 bold', bg='white smoke', width='20').pack(side='bottom')

Msg = StringVar()
Label(root, text="Enter Text", font='arial 15 bold', bg='white smoke').place(x=20, y=60)

entry_field = Entry(root, textvariable=Msg, width=50)
entry_field.place(x=20, y=100)


def Text_to_speech():
    message = entry_field.get()
    speech = gTTS(text=message)
    speech.save('DataFlair.mp3')
    playsound('DataFlair.mp3')
    os.remove('DataFlair.mp3')


def Exit():
    root.destroy()


def Reset():

    Msg.set("")


Button(root, text="PLAY", font='arial 15 bold', command=Text_to_speech, width='4').place(x=25, y=140)

Button(root, font='arial 15 bold', text='EXIT', width='4', command=Exit, bg='OrangeRed1').place(x=100, y=140)

Button(root, font='arial 15 bold', text='RESET', width='6', command=Reset).place(x=175, y=140)

root.mainloop()
```

In the above code, can play 'DataFlair.mp3' (which is in the same folder where the main program is stored)  for one time on the next time it shows error which is given below

```
Error 259 for command:
        play DataFlair.mp3 wait
    The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benof\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\pyprojects\voicereg\main.py", line 24, in Text_to_speech
    playsound('DataFlair.mp3')
  File "F:\voicereg\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 73, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand(u'play {}{}'.format(sound, ' wait' if block else ''))
  File "F:\voicereg\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 259 for command:
        play DataFlair.mp3 wait
    The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.
```

How to fix this error 259 in python.

Provide the solutions as soon as possibe.

Answer (score -2):

```
from pydub.playback import play

# ...

def Text_to_speech():
    message = entry_field.get()
    speech = gTTS(text=message)
    speech.save('DataFlair.mp3')
    play(sound='DataFlair.mp3')
    os.remove('DataFlair.mp3')
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of the code?